# Problems fixing a python tuple regex?

Tags: python, regex, list, python-2.7, encoding

I have a large `.txt` file that is made up of: `word1`, `word2`, `id`, `number` as follows:

```
s = '''
Vaya ir VMM03S0 0.427083
mañanita mañana RG 0.796611
, , Fc 1
buscando buscar VMG0000 1
una uno DI0FS0 0.951575
lavadora lavadora NCFS000 0.414738
con con SPS00 1
la el DA0FS0 0.972269
que que PR0CN000 0.562517
sorprender sorprender VMN0000 1
a a SPS00 0.996023
una uno DI0FS0 0.951575
persona persona NCFS000 0.98773
muy muy RG 1
especiales especial AQ0CS0 1
para para SPS00 0.999103
nosotros nosotros PP1MP000 1
, , Fc 1
y y CC 0.999962
la lo PP3FSA00 0.0277039
encontramos encontrar VMIP1P0 0.65
. . Fp 1

Pero pero CC 0.999764
vamos ir VMIP1P0 0.655914
a a SPS00 0.996023
lo el DA0NS0 0.457533
que que PR0CN000 0.562517
interesa interesar VMIP3S0 0.994868
LO_QUE_INTERESA_La lo_que_interesa_la NP00000 1
lavadora lavador AQ0FS0 0.585262
tiene tener VMIP3S0 1
una uno DI0FS0 0.951575
clasificación clasificación NCFS000 1
A+ a+ NP00000 1
, , Fc 1
de de SPS00 0.999984
las el DA0FP0 0.970954
que que PR0CN000 0.562517
ahorran ahorrar VMIP3P0 1
energía energía NCFS000 1
, , Fc 1
si si CS 0.99954
no no RN 0.998134
me me PP1CS000 0.89124
equivoco equivocar VMIP1S0 1
. . Fp 1

Lava lavar VMIP3S0 0.397388
hasta hasta SPS00 0.957698
7 7 Z 1
kg kilogramo NCMN000 1
, , Fc 1
no no RN 0.998134
está estar VAIP3S0 0.999201
nada nada RG 0.135196
mal mal RG 0.497537
, , Fc 1
se se P00CN000 0.465639
le le PP3CSD00 1
veía ver VMII3S0 0.62272
un uno DI0MS0 0.987295
gran gran AQ0CS0 1
tambor tambor NCMS000 1
( ( Fpa 1
de de SPS00 0.999984
acero acero NCMS000 0.973481
inoxidable inoxidable AQ0CS0 1
) ) Fpt 1
y y CC 0.999962
un uno DI0MS0 0.987295
consumo consumo NCMS000 0.948927
máximo máximo AQ0MS0 0.986111
de de SPS00 0.999984
49 49 Z 1
litros litro NCMP000 1
Mandos mandos NP00000 1
intuitivos intuitivo AQ0MP0 1
, , Fc 1
todo todo PI0MS000 0.43165
muy muy RG 1
bien bien RG 0.902728
explicado explicar VMP00SM 1
, , Fc 1
nada nada PI0CS000 0.850279
que que PR0CN000 0.562517
ver ver VMN0000 0.997382
con con SPS00 1
hola RG 0.90937838
como VMP00SM 1
estas AQ089FG 0.90839
la el DA0FS0 0.972269
lavadora lavadora NCFS000 0.414738
de de SPS00 0.999984
casa casa NCFS000 0.979058
de de SPS00 0.999984
mis mi DP1CPS 0.995868
padres padre NCMP000 1
Además además NP00000 1
también también RG 1
seca seco AQ0FS0 0.45723
preciadas preciar VMP00PF 1
. . Fp 1'''
```

For example for the `s` "file" I would like to extract the `ids` that start with `AQ` and `RG` followed by their `word2`, but they must ocurre **one after the other** for the above example **this words hold the one after another order**:

```
muy muy RG 1
especial especial AQ0CS0 1
```

For **example this words doesnt hold the one after another order**, so I would not like to extract them in a tuple:

```
hola RG 0.90937838
como VMP00SM 1
estas AQ089FG 0.90839
```

I would like to create a regex that extract in a tuple list only the `word2` followed by its `id` like this: `[('word2','id')]` for all the .txt file and for all the words that hold true the one after another order. **For the above example this is the only valid output:**

```
muy muy RG 1
especiales especial AQ0CS0 1
```

and

```
también también RG 1
seca seco AQ0FS0 0.45723
```

Then return them in a tuple with its full `id`, since they preserve the one after another order:

```
[('muy', 'RG', 'especial', 'AQ0CS0'), ('también', 'RG', 'seco', 'AQ0FS0')]
```

I tried the following:

in:

```
t = re.findall(r'(\w+)\s*(RG)[^\n]*\n[^\n]*?(\w+)\s*(AQ\w*)', s)
print t
```

**But my output is wrong, since it is droping the accent and some characters:**

out:

```
[('muy', 'RG', 'especial', 'AQ0CS0'), ('n', 'RG', 'seco', 'AQ0FS0')]
```

instead of, which is the correct:

```
[('muy', 'RG', 'especial', 'AQ0CS0'), ('también', 'RG', 'seco', 'AQ0FS0')]
```

Could someone help me to understand what happened with my above example and how to fix it in order to catch the `word2` and `id`that preserve the one after another ocurrence?. Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Your attempt works for me; given the `s` posted here, your `re.findall()` returns `[('muy', 'RG', 'especiales', 'AQ'), ('muy', 'RG', 'sencilla', 'AQ')]`. Are you certain `s` reflects the reality?

Comment: Do you absolutely need a regex ? or a lengthy programm is ok?

Comment: If `s` is a `unicode` string, you'd need to include `re.UNICODE` in the flags to ensure `\w` matches more than just ASCII word characters, but your given `s` has no potential matches that use anything but ASCII anyway.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks for the feedback. I must return the full `id` so i'ts wrong. By the other hand I am reading the content from a `.txt` file. I dont know why I am obtaining a null list. Any idea of how to solve this issue?. Thanks

Comment: @quickbug I dont figure out how to do this with a program (parser, lexer, maybe?). I guess this could be done easier with just a regex. Thanks for the support.

Comment: What about another regex aproach guys?. @MartijnPieters

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted the full ID included, then add that to your regular expression:

```
re.findall(r'^(\w+)\s.+\s(RG)\s[0-9.]+\n(.+)\s.+\s(AQ[A-Z0-9]+)', s, re.M)
```

Note that the `\w` class won't match non-ASCII characters. Decode `s` to `unicode` and use a Unicode regex:

```
re.findall(r'^(\w+)\s.+\s(RG)\s[0-9.]+\n(.+)\s.+\s(AQ[A-Z0-9]+)',
    s.decode('utf8'), re.M | re.UNICODE)
```

What codec to use for decoding depends on your input file; I picked UTF-8 here as an example but that is not necessarily correct.

Demo:

```
>>> re.findall(r'^(\w+)\s.+\s(RG)\s[0-9.]+\n^(.+)\s.+\s(AQ[A-Z0-9]+)',
...     s.decode('utf8'), re.M | re.UNICODE)
[(u'muy', u'RG', u'especiales', u'AQ0CS0'), (u'muy', u'RG', u'sencilla', u'AQ3948')]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Do you think this regex will work (just as an example) for a `AQ` followed by `RG` pattern?.

Comment: @newWithPython: you can use the same technique, just swap the patterns.

Comment: I must say that I am doing the following in order to retrive this pattern for all the `.txt` files in a directory: check the update:**Edit** maybe this is why this regex is not working.

Comment: @newWithPython we can't see what is in the files. The technique works just fine for your sample; you'll have to figure out what differs between `s` and the actual file contents.

Comment: Is it possible to create a regex that matches the desired outputs without using the `re.M` flag?. Thanks!

Comment: I guess the regex is wrong... I tried this aproach with the flag and in some cases I obtained this:`[('mucho', 'más más RG 1')]` instead of this:`[('mucho', 'más')]`. Any idea of why this is happening and how to solve it?. Thanks for yout advice!

Comment: Yes... I guess the regex is wrong in some cases is returning the tuple like this:`'(una uno DI0FS0 0.951575'), ('antes', 'es ser VSIP3S0 1')` instead of: `('uno DI0FS0'), ('antes', 'ser VSIP3S0')`

Comment: @newWithPython the `re.M` flag is redundant here; at no point are you using the `.` pattern to match newlines.

Comment: @newWithPython your regex uses `.+` to match everything between a first word and next pattern; losing the `re.M` will reduce the problem but perhaps you need to use `\w+` more.

Comment: @newWithPython other than that advice there isn't much more I can do.  Perhaps it is time for a new question?

Answer (score 1):

```
def code(aline):
    try:
        a,b,c,d = aline.split()
        return c[:2]
    except ValueError:
        return ''

result = []
l2 = ''
with open('texte.txt') as fp:
    for l3 in fp:
        l1, l2 = l2, l3
        if code(l1)=='RG' and code(l2)=='AQ':
            a,b,c,d = l1.split()
            e,g,h,j = l2.split()
            result.append((a, c, e, h))
print(result)
```